# Error on filling my model in MVC "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have this model

```
 public class DocumentModel
    {   
        public int documentID { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public int authorID { get; set; }
        public String AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int categoryID { get; set; }
        public String Category { get; set; }
        public int topicID { get; set; }
        public String Topic { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String DocumentBody { get; set; }
    }
```

When im about to fill my Model after making a query in mysql here's the code

```
 result = from DataRow row in data.Rows
                         select new DocumentModel()
                         {
                             documentID = (int)row["document_id"],
                             Title = row["title"].ToString(),
                             DateCreated = (DateTime)row["date_created"],
                             Description = row["description"].ToString(),
                             AuthorName = row["AuthorName"].ToString(),
                             categoryID = (int)row["category"],
                             topicID = (int)row["topicID"]
                         };
```

Im having an error in the CategoryID and TopicID the error says "Specified cast is not valid." i dont know where did i get that error i already check all the datatypes if its correct and i confirm that its all correct could you give me advice for this? did i miss some codes of wrong implementations?

before i forgot here is my Query code for MYsql

```
select a.document_id,a.title,date(a.date_created) as date_created,a.Description,c.first_name as AuthorName,ifnull(e.category_ID, 0) as category, ifnull(d.ID,0) as TopicID from tbldocument a
Inner join tbldocumenttree b on a.document_ID = b.Document_ID
left join tblcategory e on b.category_id = e.category_id
Inner join tblauthor c on a.author_id = c.author_id
left join tbldocumenttree d on d.ID = b.parent
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `int`'s throwing this error? I'm going to say it's probably the `DateTime`...

Comment: im sure.. i tried to replace the int into string and it works.. dont know what is causing this error...

Comment: What are the field types for `ID` and `category_ID` in your database?

Comment: category ID and topic ID is integer.

Comment: What is the format of the date_created value?  There are certain formats that DateTime does not recognize for which you'll need to use DateTime.ParseExact.  One way to troubleshoot this is to comment out each line individually until the exception no longer happens.  Then you'll know that the last line you commented out was the one causing the problem and can evaluate from there.

Comment: i already tried that its in the topicID and in the categoryID 

thank you for your concern i already solved the problem by parsing the value to int

Comment: Like this

`categoryID = int.Parse(row["categoryID"].ToString()), topicID = int.Parse(row["TopicID"].ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if row["category"] (same applied for row["topicID"]) is NULL in the data row because you can't cast null to non-nullable int. I notice that you are left joining your tblCategory and therefore NULL is a real possibility.

Either fix on the server using a coalescing function (i.e to force any NULL category to default to 0) or else check if row["category"]==DBNull.Value before you attempt to cast it, or indeed use Int32.TryParse and have whatever handling for a category of 0, etc.

Comment: `ifnull(e.category_ID, 0) as category, ifnull(d.ID,0)`
im using that code to handle the null values if the column is null it will return a value of 0

Comment: oops. I don't know how I missed that, too early in the morning I guess....sorry! But just as a matter of interest - if you break when this exception is thrown, what *is* the value of row["category"]?

Comment: its a null value i think the main problem is in this "ifnull(e.category_ID, 0)" i solved that problem by parsing it to int like this `categoryID = int.Parse(row["categoryID"].ToString()),
                                 topicID = int.Parse(row["TopicID"].ToString()),` thank you for your concern and i really appreciate it :)